# Тире и запятая. Приложения

Tags: запятые, тире, приложение

*В этом городе(,) — промышленном и ресурсном центре всего государства(,) — в N-ом районе, около аллеи, прогуливались...*

Нужны ли запятые в скобках?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы оформила так:

*В этом городе **— промышленном и ресурсном центре всего государства**, — в N-ом районе, около аллеи, прогуливались...*

Если убрать вставку, то запись была бы такая: В этом городе, в N-ом районе, около аллеи, прогуливались...

Здесь у нас два обособленных уточняющих обстоятельства и вставка с добавочными сведениями, отнесенная к слову "в городе".

Запятая после тире перенесенная.

Comment: Второе тире опускается, если по условиям контекста после приложения стоит запятая: *В Древней Греции некий Герострат поджег храм Артемиды в Эфесе — одно из чудес света, чтобы прославиться*.

Comment: А у меня не опускается, я читаю обособленный оборот как вставку, выделяя двумя паузами.  Если же одно тире опускается, то паузы вообще нет, получается  слитное прочтение фразы. Да и приложения здесь сомнительные, больше похожи на обстоятельства. Образцы разные бывают, да не все подходят к конкретной структуре предложения. Два разных варианта оформления, автор имеет право выбора.